# Servicio de android se cierra cuando cierro la app que lo inicia

Tags: xamarin.forms, servicio, android-service

Estoy intentando hacer un servicio que se ejecute en background cuando la app se cierre, les comparto el codigo que estoy usando:

```
Namespace myapp.droid.mynamespace

Public class miservicio : service
{
    Private LocationManager lManager;

    Public Location GetLocation()
    {
        Location ubicacion = null
        lManager = (LocationManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(LocationService);
        If(lManager.AllProviders.Count <= 0) return null;
        Var provider = lManager.GetBestProvider(criteria, true);
        If(lManager.IsProviderEnabled(provider))
        {
            ubicacion = lManger.GetLastKnownLocation(provider);
        }

        Return ubicacion;
    }

    Public override StartCommandResult(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, Int startId)
    {
        Var iniciado = false;
        Var t = new Task(() =>
        {
            Do
            {
                Iniciado = true;
                Ubicacion = GetLocation();

                If(ubicacion != null) mensaje = $"lat: {ubicacion.latitud} - long: {ubicacion.longitud}";
                Notificacion(mensaje);
                Thead.sleep(5000);
            }while(iniciado);
        });
        t.start();

        Return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    Public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        Return null;
    }

    Public override OnTaskRrmoved(Intent intent)
    {
         Base.OnTaskRemoves(intent);
        Var intent2 = new Intent(this, typeof(miservicio));
        Var pIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(this, 1, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);
    }
}
```

Y en mi activity lo inicio asi:

```
Void IniciarServicio()
{
    Var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(Miservicio));
    Application.Context.StartService(intent);
}
```

Y lo llamo en el OnCreate de mi activity, el servicio se cierra apenas cierro la app completamente, le ha sucedido a alguien anteriormente? 
Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida gracias!

Comment: ¿Pero eso es [tag:c#]? Porque a puro ojo se ve que no compila.

Comment: @NaCl si es c#, no puse todo a full detalle porque publico desde mi celular y es tedio escribir codigo desde aqui, a lo que quiero hacer referencia es al codigo del servicio como tal, como hacer que el servicio continue incluso si se cierra la app que lo iniciA